# How to optimize "Build Automatically" for a Maven project in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm working on a large project with 100+ modules (and pom.xml files). The maven build on command line completes in ~2 minutes. However the "Build Automatically" in Eclipse takes 10+ minutes.

How to optimize the automatic build in Eclipse?

Comment: can you close some of the projects?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.